# Multiple conditions on Timer

Tags: vb.net, winforms, timer

Can someone guide me or correct my code. I have multiple conditions in my Timer.
Each Button runs on 1 Timer but each Button clicked has different code or conditions on the timer. The problem is, only one condition will work.
If I click the first Button, the condition for the first Button will run but when I click the second Button, the first condition will still run.

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    ''progressbar(KryptonBorderEdge2) timer
    KryptonBorderEdge2.Width = KryptonBorderEdge2.Width + 1

    Dim curWidth = KryptonBorderEdge2.Width
    Dim percentage = (Double.Parse(curWidth) / Double.Parse(404) * 100.0).ToString("#0.00") ''to get percentage
    KryptonLabel5.Text = percentage.ToString + " %" ''404 is the max width or the 100% 

    If KryptonBorderEdge2.Width = 404 Then
        Timer1.Enabled = False
    End If

    ''CONNECT button is clicked
    If hardwareConnect = True Then
        If KryptonLabel5.Text = "50.00 %" Then
            Timer1.Interval = 10
            Label2.Text = "Hardware Found. Now attempting to connect."
        ElseIf KryptonLabel5.Text.Contains("100") Then
            KryptonComboBox1.Text = "OMNIKEY"
            Label2.Text = "Hardware successfully connected!"
            hardwareConnect = False
            Timer1.Enabled = False
        End If
    End If

    ''CHECK PORT button is clicked
    If checkingPort = True Then
        If KryptonLabel5.Text.Contains("100") Then
            MsgBox("Card format: JCOP S3CC9P9" + vbNewLine + "Connected on COM4", vbOKOnly)
            KryptonComboBox2.Text = "JCOP S3CC9P9"
            Label2.Text = "..."
            checkingPort = False
            Timer1.Enabled = False
        End If
    End If

    ''REMOVE SAVED DATA is clicked 
    If KryptonLabel5.Text = "89.00 %" Then
        Label2.Text = "Finishing things up."
        If KryptonLabel5.Text.Contains("100") Then
            removeAll()
            MsgBox("Data Successfully Removed!", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
            Label2.Text = "..."
            Timer1.Enabled = False
        End If
    End If

    ''START/WRITE DATA button is clicked
    If writeData = True Then
        If KryptonLabel5.Text = "20.00 %" Then
            Label2.Text = "Blank Card detected."
        ElseIf KryptonLabel5.Text = "30.00 %" Then
            Label2.Text = "Writing account name..."
        ElseIf KryptonLabel5.Text = "40.00 %" Then
            Label2.Text = "Inserting ARQC Key and Master Key..."
        ElseIf KryptonLabel5.Text = "50.00 %" Then
            Label2.Text = "Confirming Expiry Date..."
        ElseIf KryptonLabel5.Text = "60.00 %" Then
            Label2.Text = "Generating PIN..."
        ElseIf KryptonLabel5.Text = "70.00 %" Then
            Label2.Text = "Writing PIN and CVV..."
        ElseIf KryptonLabel5.Text = "80.00 %" Then
            Label2.Text = "Confirming Track1/Track2/Track3..."
        ElseIf KryptonLabel5.Text = "90.00 %" Then
            Label2.Text = "Finalizing everything. Please wait for a while..."
            Timer1.Interval = 1000
        ElseIf KryptonLabel5.Text.Contains("100") Then
            Label2.Text = "Successfully writing data to the card!"
            Timer1.Enabled = False
            writeData = False
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: The logic seems to be backwards from how I would expect to do it.  Instead of posting progress as steps are completed, you appear to be completing steps as a result of posting progress.  It's also not entirely clear why you're doing this with a timer at all---e.g. an `Async` workflow might give the same results with a much more intuitive flow through the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only one condition to be true at a given time, don't use Booleans. Instead, create an enum with possible operations and a variable to store the current operation

```vb
Enum Operation
    None
    HardwareConnect
    CheckingPort
    WriteData
End Enum

Dim currentOperation As Operation
```

Now, when a button is clicked set the current operation. Like this only one type of operation can be active.

```vb
Private Sub ConnectButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ConnectButton.Click
    currentOperation = Operation.HardwareConnect
End Sub
```

Your sub then looks like this:

```vb
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    'progressbar(KryptonBorderEdge2) timer
    KryptonBorderEdge2.Width = KryptonBorderEdge2.Width + 1

    Dim curWidth = KryptonBorderEdge2.Width
    Dim percentage = (Double.Parse(curWidth) / Double.Parse(404) * 100.0).ToString("#0.00") ''to get percentage
    KryptonLabel5.Text = percentage.ToString + " %" ''404 is the max width or the 100% 

    If KryptonBorderEdge2.Width = 404 Then
        Timer1.Enabled = False
    End If

    If currentOperation = Operation.HardwareConnect Then 'CONNECT button is clicked
       ...
    ElseIf currentOperation = Operation.CheckingPort Then 'CHECK PORT button is clicked
       ...
    End If

    ' REMOVE SAVED DATA is clicked 
    If KryptonLabel5.Text = "89.00 %" Then
        ...
    End If

    If currentOperation = Operation.WriteData Then
        ' START/WRITE DATA button is clicked
        ...
    End If
End Sub
```

Instead of setting the Booleans to `False` you can set `currentOperation = Operation.None`

```vb
Sub StopOperations()
    Timer1.Enabled = False
    currentOperation = Operation.None
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It really helped me